# Access to a file within a subfolder in APPDATA directory

Tags: python, xml, appdata

I'm trying to open an XML file located within a subfolder the APPDATA dircetory. Obviously the folder changes depending on which user is logged in:

I have no issue if specify the name of the user, for example:

```
\\C:\Users\USER\AppData\Roaming\Folder1\Folder2\File.xml
```

However I wish to eliminate the "C:\Users\USER\Appdata\Roaming" part and swap it with this:

```
\\C:APPDATA\Folder1\Folder2\File.xml
```

Here is the error I receive:

```
OSError: Error reading file '\\C:APPDATA\Folder1\Folder2\File.xml': failed to load external entity "//Folder1\Folder2\File.xml"
```

Answer (score 2):

A couple of ways:

```py
import os
from pathlib import Path

option1 = fr'{os.environ['appdata']}\Folder1\Folder2\File.xml'
option2 = Path(os.environ['appdata']) / r'Folder1\Folder2\File.xml'
print(option1)
print(option2)
```

Output:

```
C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Roaming\Folder1\Folder2\File.xml
C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Roaming\Folder1\Folder2\File.xml
```